# AngularJS + Karma + Jasmine: beforeEach() - angular.module vs angular.mock.module

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

- I am new to Jasmine and Karma testing.
- I am trying to Unit test AngularJs Service.
- While writing Specs, I came around two types of Code for injecting Module.

**1st Type**

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app"));
```

**2nd Type**

```
beforeEach(function () {
    angular.module("app");
});
```

- Can anybody explain the difference between the above two in simple plain English with a simple example.
- And also, which code to use in what kind of scenario?
- I tried to Google it, but was not able to find a proper answer.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

From angular-mocks.js

```
window.module = angular.mock.module = function() {
...
```

More info:

http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/05/24/ngmock-fundamentals-angularjs-unit-testing/
https://github.com/bbraithwaite/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L2259
https://gist.github.com/trinitroglycerin/68754b920df83a977f12#gistcomment-2851474

To enable usage of 'module' add this to webpack configuration:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    //...config
    webpack: {
      //...webpack config
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          module: 'window.module',
        }),
      ],
    }
  });
};
```